# How to detect big jumps and quick reversals in panel time-series data in r

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, panel, anomaly-detection

I have a time-series panel dataset which is structured in the following way:

```
df <- data.frame(
  year = c(2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L),
  id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
  c = c(11L, 13L, 13L, 16L, 15L, 15L)
)

#>   year id  c
#> 1 2012  1 11
#> 2 2013  1 26
#> 3 2014  1 13
#> 4 2012  2 16
#> 5 2013  2 15
#> 6 2014  2 19
```

Within each id, I would like to spot huge unusual changes and subsequent reversals in column c (i.e., the variable doubles or shrinks 2 times within one period similar to row 2 in the sample dataset and quickly reverts back to normal in the next period)

The way I would like to define the reversal to normal is to determine whether if you go back around the value (within a specified range) before the
change the value goes back to for example +/- 25% of the original
value).

I would like to be able to specify the period to look for reversal (e.g. 3 periods/years)

To summarize I would like to be able to detect a huge jump or shrink of two times or more within one period that also quickly reverts back to normal (25% of the original value) within a specified period (3 years).

My end goal is to determine whether there are some possible errors in the database and select all the ids that have such errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `lag` function to look backwards. It respects groups specified in a `group_by`.

The default for `lag` (or `lead`) is to shift to the immediate row ahead or behind the current one, but if you supply an integer as the second argument (2 in this case) it will check values further back.

`lag` and `lead` return `NA` when there isn't a row available since we've reached the boundary of a (grouped) dataframe, so here I'm using `coalesce` to force those `NA`s into `FALSE`. You could also have utilized the default argument of the original functions, but this seemed easier.

```
df <- data.frame(
  year = c(2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L),
  id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
  c = c(11L, 26L, 13L, 16L, 15L, 15L)
)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(flag = (lag(c) >= 2*lag(c, 2) | lag(c) <= 0.5*lag(c, 2)) 
                & abs(1 - c/(lag(c, 2))) < 0.25) %>%
  mutate(flag = coalesce(flag, FALSE))

# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   id [2]
   year    id     c flag 
  <int> <int> <int> <lgl>
1  2012     1    11 FALSE
2  2013     1    26 FALSE
3  2014     1    13 TRUE 
4  2012     2    16 FALSE
5  2013     2    15 FALSE
6  2014     2    15 FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. What would be the most efficient way of subsetting all the ids that had a TRUE value into a new panel dataframe which includes the whole series for that specific id?

Comment: take the resulting dataframe and do `group_by(id) %>% filter(max(flag) == TRUE)`. This will filter only for `id`s that have at least one flagged row